# Validate if input contains only special characters without any numbers with it

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem:** I'm trying to validate when the user only inputted special characters without typing any number with it.

I'm using this expression

```
/^\+?[0-9 \.-]+$/
```

to accept only '+' sign, numbers, dots, hypens, and spaces when validating fax. This is working fine.

But with that expression the user can input `--------------` without typing any number and is accepted because it contains hypen.

**Question:** Is there's a way to check if the input contains number? not just all special characters?

**UPDATE:** 

This is an example of valid accepted input.

`+1-2 12-98765.43` > the requirement is it should only accept '+' sign, hypen, numbers, spaces and dots.

Comment: Can you add all possible valid input strings. i.e. fax numbers

Comment: I added a sample output. That's their only requirement for the output.

Comment: Check [`^\+?\d-\d\s\d{2}-\d{5}\.\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/mD9cF3/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest option is to have additional regex checks for each condition. E.g. have a regex check for just the presence of numbers `/[0-9]/` and another check for just the presence of special characters `/[ +.-]/`. Run these only after testing that nothing undesirable exists in the string.

```
var whole = /^\+?[0-9 \.-]+$/
function validate(input) {
    // input only contains valid things
    if (!input.test(whole)) { return "Input must contain only numbers, spaces, and + . or -"; }
    // input contains each required thing
    if (!input.test(/[0-9]/)) { return "Number required"; }
    if (!input.test(/[ .-]/)) { return "Special character required"; }

    // You can also test the first character of the string with charAt()
    if (input.charAt(0) !== "+") { return "Input does not begin with +"; }
    return "Valid input";
}
```

I notice that your regex tests for zero or one plus, followed by a character in the list [numbers, spaces, periods, or hyphens]. Do you mean to test for any number of pluses? The regex I've posted (`/[ +.-]/`) should work for all the characters you want to allow.

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but if you want to verify that a specific single character or pattern exists in a string, you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
// Require at least one hyphen
if (input.indexOf("-") === -1) { return "Please include a hyphen"; }
```

**Update**: If, as in your example, there is only one plus and it is at the beginning, then you do indeed want the `\+?` bit. However, you don't need to escape the period inside of square brackets. Supposing the plus were required, you could use [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to test this. See updated example.

Answer (score 1):

> This is an example of valid accepted input.
>
> +1-2 12-98765.43 > the requirement is it should only accept '+' sign, hypen, numbers, spaces

Accepted input appear to accept `.` character as well ?

Try `^(\+\d-\d \d{2}-\d+)(?:\.\d+|$)`

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^(\+\d-\d \d{2}-\d+)(?:\.\d+|$)" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `lookahead`.

```
^(?=.*[0-9])\+?[0-9 \.-]+$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/9